# NEW/Delete Heap Corruption Detected : CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer

Tags: c++, memory, delete-operator

In the following snippet, I am trying to de-allocate the dynamic memory used to create the a Set using New but after erasing the nodes of SET, if I try to delete.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::set<char *> myset;
    std::set<char *>::iterator it;  
    char *l_ptr1, *l_ptr2;

    std::cout <<"Before Insertion::Address of myset " << &myset<<endl;
    //l_ptr1 = (char*)malloc(256*sizeof(char*));    
    //l_ptr2 = (char*)malloc(256*sizeof(char*));
    l_ptr1 = new char(256);
    l_ptr2 = new char(256);
    printf("Before Insertion ::Address of l_ptr1 %x\n", l_ptr1);
    printf("Before Insertion ::Address of l_ptr2 %x\n", l_ptr2);

    std::cin>>l_ptr1;
    myset.insert(l_ptr1);
    std::cin>>l_ptr2;
    myset.insert(l_ptr2);
    std::cout <<"After Insertion::Address of myset " << &myset<<endl;

    std::cout << "Myset Contains :: Value and It's Address "<<endl;
    it = myset.begin(); 
    std::cout<<*it<<"\t"<<&(*it)<<endl; ++it;
    std::cout<<*it<<"\t"<<&(*it)<<endl;
    std::cout << endl;

    it = myset.begin();
    myset.erase(it++);
    std::cout <<"After First Node Deletion ::Address of myset " << &myset<<endl;
    std::cout <<"Before free(l_ptr1) :: l_ptr1:: " <<l_ptr1 <<endl;
    //free(l_ptr1);
    delete[] l_ptr1;
    std::cout <<"After free(l_ptr1)  :: l_ptr1:: " <<l_ptr1 <<endl;
    myset.erase(it);
    std::cout <<"After Second Node Deletion ::Address of myset " << &myset<<endl;   
    std::cout <<"Before free(l_ptr2) :: l_ptr2:: " <<l_ptr2 <<endl;
    //free(l_ptr2);
    delete[] l_ptr2;
    std::cout <<"After  free(l_ptr2) :: l_ptr2:: " <<l_ptr2 <<endl;

    printf("After All Node Deletion ::Address of l_ptr1 %x\n", l_ptr1);
    printf("After All Node Deletion ::Address of l_ptr2 %x\n", l_ptr2);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting following error.

**HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block(#150) at 0x005B5380.
CRT Detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer.**

Comment: `new char(256);` -> `new char[256];`, you need to fix your `printf` formats as well. **Turn your compiler warnings on**.

Answer (score 9):

First let me quote a programmer I learned a lot from:

> Your C++ code contains a bug: you are not using std::string.

That said, if you *insist* on making life harder and using char arrays, you should check whether your code actually does what you want:

```
l_ptr1 = new char(256);
```

This line is allocating *a single char* and assigning the number 256.

```
l_ptr1 = new char[256];
```

This line is allocating 256 characters.

Answer (score 3):

```
new char(256)
```

allocates a single character, with the value 256 (after conversion to `char` type). You treat it as an array, so you probably meant

```
new char[256]
```

which allocates an array.

Now your problem is that the program will explode if either input is longer than your arbitrary limit of 256. It's better to use `std::string` to represent a string, rather than trying to juggle raw memory yourself.

Answer (score -1):

You should use following for deletion

```
delete l_ptr1;
delete l_ptr2;
```

not `[]` as you have allocated using `new` not `new []`.

`new char(256)` will allocate one `char` and initialize it will be 256.

Or

I think you want to allocated character array, hence

```
l_ptr1 = new char[256];
l_ptr2 = new char[256];
```

Use `new []` operator for allocation.

Comment: I can't upvote this. Although it's factually correct, it's somewhat misleading as you begin with a false premise, give the wrong advice, then only half correct it towards the end of the answer when you realised it's the `new` that needs to change and not the `delete`.

Comment: This is totally terrible and holy crap please don't ever recommend `new[]` to anybody.